# Unable to redirect to a page using Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I used the Response.Redirect control to move to a page called "Equipment.aspx" and it was working fine but after a while it started to get redirected to the page "OpeningPage.aspx".

I tried creating those pages again and changed the name of the page from "OpeningPage.aspx" to "Opening_Page.aspx" and when i tried running it showed http:404 file not found error and RequestedURL:/OpeningPage.aspx

```
 SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(con);
    sqlcon.Open();
 string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM UserAccounts WHERE UserName = '" + username.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, sqlcon);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    sqlcon.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        string checkpassword = "SELECT Password FROM UserAccounts WHERE UserName = '" + username.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmdt = new SqlCommand(checkpassword, sqlcon);
        string tem = cmdt.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        if (tem == password.Text)
        {

            Session["usersession"] = username.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Equipment.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("incorrect password");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("incorrect username");
    }
```

the following is the code for the "Equipment.aspx.cs" page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(Session["usersession"] != null )
    {
        usernam.Text = Session["usersession"].ToString();
    } 
 else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
}

protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.RemoveAll();
   Response.Redirect("~/Opening_Page.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Note that your code is subject to a [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: please provide us your route config

Comment: `Clean` and `Rebuild` your solution

Comment: Is it that within the Equipment aspx you are redirecting to the opening Page.aspx? Place a breakpoint in the equipment. Aspx page load and see if there are redirects via script in the page